# Magento 2.4.4 - issue with setup:di:compile

Tags: magento2, php, setup-di-compile, token

I recently upgraded my site to Magento 2.4.4 with PHP 8.1 and noticed that when I try to run the command '$ php bin / magento setup: di: compile' the process stops at 1/9 with this error message :

```
 1/9 [==>------------------]  11% 1 sec 119.0 MiBsyntax error, unexpected token "match", expecting identifier#0 /var/www/html/magento24/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(117)
```

I've done a lot of research and it appears to be a PHP 8 problem. How can I fix this bug?

Thanks for any help

***UPDATE***
I saw that the class generate this issue is "Magento\Elasticsearch\SearchAdapter\Query\Builder\QueryInterface"

```
namespace Magento\Elasticsearch\SearchAdapter\Query\Builder;

use Magento\Framework\Search\Request\QueryInterface as RequestQueryInterface;

/**
 * @api
 * @since 100.1.0
 */
interface QueryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param array $selectQuery
     * @param RequestQueryInterface $requestQuery
     * @param string $conditionType
     * @return array
     * @since 100.1.0
     */
    public function build(
        array $selectQuery,
        RequestQueryInterface $requestQuery,
        $conditionType
    );
}
```

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: are you sure you're on PHP 8? `match` was introduced in 8.0.0 so it should get recognized. You get this problem if you're on php 7 or lower

Comment: when i'm on php 7 i don't have this problem.
It shows up when I change the php version of my server locally and choose version 8.1

Comment: In this case I don't have a solution, but I  think I can help to find the faulty file. GO to the `Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php` class at the specifiel line `117` and above the line `$this->includeClass($className, $fileItemPath);` add this `echo  $className . "\n";`. now when you run di:compile you should see the class names being processed going through your console. and it will stop at the faulty one.

Comment: Thanks man for the help! I saw that the last class it printed to me is: "Magento\Elasticsearch\SearchAdapter\Query\Builder\QueryInterface". I put its content in my question. Do you have any suggestions on how to correct this? Thanks

Comment: Could it be a configuration problem with my server extension?

Comment: this is strange. there is no "match" in the class you mentioned. Did you put the debug "echo" line above or below `$this->includeClass($className, $fileItemPath);` ?

Comment: @Marius you're pro man

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you remove all modules from the vendor folder before updating to a complete new Magento version. I suspect some files are hanging in IDE or Docker sync.

So: rm -rf vendor/* && composer update/install.

Comment: Yes, correct man! I found files named as Match.php which were inside the module-elasticsearch folder. By removing these files the compile command works like a charm. Thanks to all for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

For me, it is because of the **Smile_ElasticsuiteCore** extension issue with PHP 8.

Seems not compatible with PHP 8. Cannot use 'match' as an identifier. It is a reserved keyword since PHP 8.0

See below class names:

- app/code/Smile/ElasticsuiteCore/Search/Request/Query/Match.php
- app/code/Smile/ElasticsuiteCore/Search/Adapter/Elasticsuite/Request/Query/Builder/Match.php

Answer (score 0):

You may face this issue if your files under following modules are not updated correctly. (I was trying to update from Adobe Commerce 2.3.5-p2 to 2.4.5-p1 version)

```
\vendor\magento\framework\Search\Request\Query
\vendor\magento\framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Query\Builder
\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-mock-objects\src\Builder
\vendor\magento\module-elasticsearch\SearchAdapter\Query\Builder
\vendor\magento\module-catalog-graph-ql\Model\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Query\Builder
\vendor\magento\module-customer-segment\Controller\Adminhtml\Index
```

For me I had files named as *Match.php* on the above mentioned location.
So make sure that your Vendor folder has updated correctly.

If you still have the issue search your Vendor folder for files named as Match.php.